# Xcode 8 - Link dylib relative to executable runtime path

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, xcode8

I have a fairly large project in Xcode 8.2, which consists of one big dynamic library `libarc.dylib` and several other executable targets. One of these targets runs the unit and integration tests on my library.

I have set the Xcode build location to be relative to my project directory, instead of the default Xcode derived data location.

Building and running my project's targets works fine from within Xcode, but when I run my tests executable, from the build product directory, via terminal, I get the following error.

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libarc.dylib`

`Referenced from: /Users/<username>/programming/<project>/Build/Products/Debug/.Tests`

`Reason: image not found`

`[1]    44968 abort    ./Tests`

So obviously the dynamic library is not loading. Upon checking the `local/lib` path, I notice that my library is not installed.

Running `otool -L Tests` gives me

`/usr/local/lib/libarc.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`

This library is project-specific, and I would like to load it from my project Build location. Preferably, at some stage, everything will be bundled into an `.app`.

How can I set the dylib loading path, for the `Tests` target, to point to the `libarc.dylib` in its run path?

I have found some information, that suggests `Embedding Binaries` into my target, but as of Xcode 8.2, I can not find this section under the `General` tab, for my target.

Beyond just converting my library to a static library, what other options do I have? I don't think its appropriate to have the library installed system wide in the release. Would a static library be more appropriate, given my requirements. I'll also add, the library consists of a game engine, so performance is key.

As a final note, many of the engine core systems are implemented as singletons.